# Is there a better ticketing system to check PostgreSQL issues?

Tags: postgresql

I want to keep track of an issue in PostgreSQL. This mailing list tool that they have is hard.

Is there an easier way to track their issues, open one and track it?

Like a mirror system they have in Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative.

Many people would like to have a bug tracker, and there are regularly spirited attempts to introduce one. They usually fail because of lack of buy-in by the community.

- One of the problems is that it must be possible to continue using e-mail as an interface.
- The other problem is that PostgreSQL does not want to become dependent on third-party tools.

PostgreSQL has been here for over twenty years, and we want to stay around for more. Tools come and go, e-mail will remain.

The archives offer a [pretty good search functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1).

For example, if you want to search for previous discussions about bug trackers, [this search](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&q=bug%20tracker&l=1&d=-1&s=r) on the Hackers list will bring many results.